# How are entities stored in unreal engine 3?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, cheat-engine

I am currently trying to create a hack for Borderlands 2. One of the features I am trying to create is a Kill All feature which will iterate through each entity saved to my vector entity struct and set their health to 0. This is easy for me to do on other games but I am having major trouble on this game.

I found a pointer that shows me the true health value of the entity I am looking it but I noticed that in certain regions of the map the addresses change vastly. For example, I may find 7-8 entity's near me that start with the same address (Ex. 0x79C8000+)

But after I leave to go to another area the entity's I find here are vastly different in memory location. (Ex. 0x01CD0000+)

And I understand that such a large map would require things like that to happen, especially if I move to far away from a certain region of entity's they are unloaded from the world and the address value is set to 0 and no longer correctly points to the entity's health when I move back to said region and they are loaded back in.

The things that bothers me is that there has to be an array that stores every entity that is CURRENTLY loaded in memory, regardless if its just an object entity and non NPC because I'm almost certain there is one because other people are able to find it.

Any ideas??

Comment: You might consider adding `unreal-engine4` tag to the question, since there is no generic Unreal Engine tag.

Comment: Sounds good, will do.